# Why won't Typescript let me access the property of an object using bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have the following interfaces:

```js
interface IAnswersCount {
  nintendo: number;
  microsoft: number;
  sony: number;
}

interface IState {
  counter: number;
  questionId: number;
  question: string;
  answerOptions: AnswerType[];
  answer: string;
  answersCount: IAnswersCount;
  result: string;
}
```

and a state inside of a functional component, written like so:

```js
 const [state, setState] = React.useState<IState>({
    counter: 0,
    questionId: 1,
    question: '',
    answerOptions: [],
    answer: '',
    answersCount: {
      nintendo: 0,
      microsoft: 0,
      sony: 0,
    },
    result: '',
  });
```

Somewhere in the code I am trying to dynamically access one of the nested properties of the `answersCount` property. The way I am doing it is like:

```js
const doSomething = (answer: string): void => {

// other things happen here
   const value = state.answerOptions[answer as keyof IAnswersCount]
}
```

I get the following error which I can't rid of, no matter how I write the code:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

I can't figure it out what I am doing wrong, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The type of  `state.answerOptions` is `AnswerType[]`, so it's an array. Why are you trying to access it with a string key? The type of `answer as keyof IAnswersCount` would be `nintendo | microsoft | sony`, it makes no sense to use this as a key for `answerOptions` array. You have to rethink your model if you want to access the options based on an answer, maybe using a map/object literal.

Comment: Did you mean to write `state.answersCount[answer]` instead of `state.answerOptions[answer]`?

Comment: @ robertgr991 Oh, totally. Of course it is not working, I was trying to access the wrong property. I actually wanted to target `answersCount`. My bad. Thx!

Comment: @Bergi correct. The downside of working late. Thx.

Comment: And by the way, set a full state object with useState isn't the best practise. You want to breakdown each property into a useState call for each one or either use a reducer here.

Comment: @Dash you are actually right. I wrote the code based on someone else's and I was thinking the same thing. Glad to see I was on to something.

Comment: Using objects in state is completely acceptable, especially when the properties within the object are linked. For example, property `a` and property `b` are required to calculate property `c.` Due to state be asynchronous, having 3 separate states to manage these properties means that there's no guarantee that when property `c` is recalculated that `a` and `b` are update-to-date. Using a reducer is not required, but may be easier to understand.

Comment: @CasiaHospi Good you're using TypeScript which will catch such mistakes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're indexing the wrong state property: `state.answerOptions` (which is an array) instead of `state.answersCount`.

I think you mean to do:

```
const doSomething = (answer: string): void => {
  // other things happen here
  const value = state.answersCount[answer as keyof IAnswersCount]
}
```

or, without the assertion:

```
const doSomething = (answer: keyof IAnswersCount): void => {
  // other things happen here
  const value = state.answersCount[answer]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your key, i edit your interface:

```js
interface IAnswersCount {
  [key: string]: number,
  nintendo: number;
  microsoft: number;
  sony: number;
}

// [key: string]: number
// is not a new property, is a map access definition
```

Comment: I am afraid `any` defeats the purpose of using Typescript.

Comment: Look, i edit your interface, pay attention to first line

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 problems:

1. You should use a narrower type for 'answer'
2. I think you want to use `answersCount` not `answerOptions`, because `answerOptions` is in your example an array of `AnswerType`, not an object with string properties

```js
const doSomething = (answer: keyof IAnswersCount): void => {

   // other things happen here
   const value = state.answersCount[answer];
}
```

If you did mean to use `answersOptions`, share the type of `AnswerType`.